# RetrieveSalesforceObjects to retrieve lead records based on email submit

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Trying to retrieve lead object record based on email to pre fill the textbox when submitted. I can't seem to find any examples of "RetrieveSalesforceObjects ". can someone please point me in the right direction for the code below:

```
<body>
%%[ var @rs
set @Email = QueryParameter("emailaddress")
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'Email', '=', @Email)
Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"Id")
]%%


         <form action="http://example.com/" method="POST" target='_parent'>
   <input type="hidden" id="p" name="p" value="y">
   <input type="hidden" id="rid" name="rid" value = "%%=v(@Id)=%%" />
   <input type="hidden" id="SubmitDate" name="SubmitDate" value="%%=Now()=%%">
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>First Name
                    </td>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                      <input  type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"  value = "%%=v(@FirstName)=%%" />
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Last Name*
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name = "lastname" value = "%%=v(@LastName)=%%" required />
                    </td>
                      </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Email*
                    </td>
                     <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="email" id="emailaddress" name = "emailaddress"  value = "%%=v(@Email)=%%" required/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Mobile Phone*
                    </td>
                     <tr>
                      <td>
                        <input type="tel" id="mobilephone" name = "mobilephone" value = "%%=v(@MobilePhone)=%%"   required/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                   <input type="checkbox" name="Email_Opt_in" id="Email_Opt_in" value="True"> Durham College values the opportunity to provide you with information. Please click here to allow us to continue to contact you via email. </td> </tr>

        </table>
                  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>   


  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers -

1) Define all Variables
2) Retrieve the data from the resultset.
3) Display in the form

See code snippet below. P.S. Added Null Check too :)

```
%%[ var @rs, @Email, @row, @Id, @Fname, @Lname
set @Email = QueryParameter("emailaddress")
Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id, FirstName,LastName', 'Email', '=', @Email)

// Null check
IF NOT Empty(@rs) THEN 
    Set @row = ROW(@rs,1)
    Set @Id = FIELD(@row,"Id")
    Set @Fname = FIELD(@row,"FirstName")
    Set @Lname = FIELD(@row,"LastName")
ENDIF
```

Use %%=v(@Fname)=%% & %%=v(@Lname)=%% within HTML tags to display the relevant values.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet much appreciated. It's not pre-filling the content. I'm asuming I need more that just RetrieveSalesforceObjects to allow the form to connect to our Sales Cloud instance correct? I was also looking at puling the data from Marketing Clouds Data extension and I found this resource (http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/updating_a_dynamic_list_of_fields_within_a_single_data_extension_record/)

Comment: there's a section there : /* Build Subscriber Object & set properties in order to update */
SET @sub_de = CreateObject("DataExtensionObject")
SetObjectProperty(@sub_de,"CustomerKey", "Downstream_Subscriber_Preference") Any chance you know what syntax are require here. My data extention name is "WebForm_Tour" I'm assuming I replace DataExtensionObject with that but I'm unsure of the next line

Comment: Marketing Cloud Connector should be set up with the Sales Cloud Instance in Question. If that's working, you should be able to try and query a lead. To debug, start by querying a hardcoded lead ID and see if that works.

Comment: You can pull lead data from a Data Extension, but the data needs to exist in the DE in the first place. Explore the LookupOrderedRows function for Data Extensions.

Comment: Not Empty is not working for me. @rs does in fact have data, but Not Empty keeps my other variables from getting set. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

Just to update the above and answer the comment from garek007 (years late...) - the null check will work if you change the IF statement as follows:

`// Null check
IF rowcount(@rs) > 0 THEN`